# How to display Html table in textview?

Tags: android, html, textview

I want to display text inside textview using this code:

```
Html.fromHtml("<html><body><table style=width:100%><tr><td><B>No</td><td><B>Product Name</td><td><B>Qty</td><td><B>Amount</td></tr></body></html>");
```

But result is not in correct format result look like this:

```
NoPRoductNameQtyAmount
```

please suggest what i am doing wrong in this code.

Comment: First: html tags are always lower cases only. So B must become b. Also you should close all the tags so for example <b>Amount </b>. Fix these and then see if it works

Comment: Thanks @eduyayo.... i am doing same as above post suggest but output is not correct.

Comment: @LelioFaieta: I don't know what `fromHtml()` does, but _HTML itself_ allows both upper and lower case in tag names. You also need to provide close tags for the _`<table>`_ and _`<b>`_ elements. The close tags for the other elements are optional. Again, the `fromHtml()` method may impose further restrictions that I am unaware of.

Answer (score 11):

`fromHtml()` does not support `<table>` and related tags. Your choices are:

1. Reformat your text to avoid tables
2. Use `WebView` to render your HTML table
3. Use native widgets and containers (e.g., `TableLayout`) for your table

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using html table inside a TextView I've solved formatting normal text into a table like text, adding white spaces into the text to have a tidy structure.

This is the code:

```
String lines[] = getItem(position).toString().split("\n");
String print = "";
String parts[] = null;
String tmp = "";
int weight = 0;
for (int i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
   if (!lines[i].equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
       parts = lines[i].split(":", 2);
       tmp = "";
       Paint textPaint = text.getPaint();
       float width = textPaint.measureText(parts[0]);
       float wslength = textPaint.measureText(" ");
       for (int j = 0; j < (220 - Math.round(width))/Math.round(wslength); j++) {
           tmp = tmp + " ";
       }
       if (print.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
           print = print + parts[0] + tmp + Html.fromHtml(""+parts[1]+"");
       } else {
           print = print + "\n" + parts[0] + tmp + parts[1];
       }
   }
}
```

You can find more explanations here:
http://blog.blupixelit.eu/convert-text-to-table-in-android-sdk/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about change the way to just render table by webview, the other tags render by textview ? Recently i finish a demo to overcome this. So we first need separate`<table>` with others supported tags, which will like change "`<p>**<p> blabala <table>balabla </table> blabla <p>**<p>`" to three separated strings

- `<p>**<p> blabala`
- `<table>balabla </table>`
- `blabla <p>**<p>`

Then only `<table>` included tags render by webview, the others by textview
And the result in android will be like:

```
 <ScrollView> 
   <LinearLayout>
    <TextView> 
    <WebView>  --- let the webview ATMOST measured
    <TextView>
```

So every thing goes fine as i think. check [this commit](https://github.com/brucetoo/incubator-weex/commit/330508772a10303fc0414646fce282df8e35bf65#diff-870883d1f9c2fd415043c77c32f6bfecR91) for detail

Answer (score -2):

[HtmlTextView](https://github.com/SufficientlySecure/html-textview) recently added basic support for HTML tables. It's limited, but will do the trick if all you have to worry about is  `<table>`, `<td>`, `<tr>`, and `<th>`.

Comment: doesn't handle tables properly